# Add an agent to a Quarkus native image

Tags: gradle, quarkus, agent, datadog, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to build a Quarkus project native image, and I need to introduce the Datadog agent to it. The Datadog documentation says:

> /mvnw package -Dnative
> -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args='-J-javaagent:/path/to/dd-java-agent.jar'

I'm using Gradle, so I downloaded the jar and added it as a dependency in my project and added the following line in the properties file: `quarkus.native.additional-build-args=-J-javaagent:dd-java-agent.jar`. However, Gradle seems to rename the jar by adding a hash to it, and even though I added the hash to the properties file Quarkus doesn't seem to find the file during the build of the image.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered using the [datadog quarkiverse extension (`github.com`)](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-datadog-opentracing)?

Comment: It says it's not being maintained anymore: EDIT 2022-08-04: This extension won't be maintained anymore

Comment: I'd say that this your best shot. As far as I am aware of, there is no way to "bake-in" an agent into a native image. There is, however [a feature request (`github.com`)](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1065) for this.

Comment: @ThiagoHora where did you get the `-J-javaagent:dd-java-agent.jar` suggestion from? I am interested in having a look.

FYI, running agents at native-image build time is not fully supported, see https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1065

Comment: From Datadog documentation their support team sent me.